# Possible to convert M.2 (A+E) to USB with adapter? (re: bluetooth only)

Tags: usb, bluetooth, m.2, ngff

Is it possible to convert an M.2 (A+E) adapter into a USB adapter for bluetooth only?

More specifically, I'm looking to convert the [Intel AX-200](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/sku/189347/intel-wifi-6-ax200-gig/specifications.html) M.2 drive into  a USB dongle but I only need bluetooth and not wifi.

The specifications show the following:

```
System Interface Type:  Wi-Fi(PCIe), BT(USB)
```

Therefore, I'm wondering if I can take the M.2 A+E USB pins (pins 3 and 5 according to the [M.2 pinout for A+E keying](https://pinoutguide.com/HD/M.2_NGFF_connector_pinout.shtml)) and connect them to a USB port?

I'm aware there are lots of USB bluetooth adapters, but only a few support Bluetooth 5.1 and almost none support 5.2 and 5.3.  I'm also hoping to use the Intel bluetooth stack instead of Realtek which is used by most of the other adapters.

Comment: Theoretically possibly yes. Realistically? Most likely not. // I question your goals. There is no Intel Bluetooth stack. There is only Microsoft nowadays.

Comment: Why is it not realistically possible?  Also, I'm referring to the Linux Bluetooth stack and not Windows.